# Modifying model attributes in Ruby on Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a Ruby on Rails model that looks like this (db/schema.rb):

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "other"
  end
```

In the `users_controller.rb` I am doing:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.email.downcase!
    @user.other = "TEST"
  end
```

and in the `show` view (`show.html.haml`):

```
User details: 
  %b #{@user.name} + #{@user.email} + #{@user.other}
```

The problem is that the `@user.other` value is not displayed at all. My guess is that the `@user.other` is `nil`, but I don't know why it's not set to `TEST`, as I set it in the `new` controller action.

In my `Users` model, I set:

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :other
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually `new` method renders `new.html.haml` which in turn could render `_form.html.haml`. Why do you inspect `show.html.haml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` and `show` actions are different.  When you set something in `new` doesn't mean that it will get shown in your `show` view.  If you had `@user.other = "TEST"` in your `create` action then you would have definitely seen "TEST" for `#{@user.other}` in  your view.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the fact that `new/show` actions are different (RoR beginner here), but I learned something new about the `create` action (thanks for the reply!).